# Markov Chain: Conditional distribution at time $t$, given $t-1$ and $t+1$

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, markov-chains, markov-process, hidden-markov-models

For a Markov process given by
$$x_t = \mu +\kappa(x_{t-1} - \mu) + \sigma \cdot \varepsilon_t $$
where $\varepsilon_t \sim N(0,1)$ and $\mu$, $\kappa$, $\sigma^2$ are the parameters, how would I find the conditional distribution $p\left(x_t \vert x_{t-1}, x_{t+1},\kappa ,\mu,\sigma^2\right)$?

The paper I'm reading says it is given by:
$$N\left(\mu + \kappa[(x_{t-1}-\mu)+(x_{t+1}-\mu)] / [1+\kappa^2], \quad\sigma^2/(1-\kappa^2)\right)$$
however I can't work out how this is derived.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to make things clear: you are looking for the conditional distribution of $X_t$ given $X_{t-1}$ and $X_{t+1}$?

Comment: @Mick Yes, exactly

Comment: A straightforward but a bit tedious application of the formulas for the conditional normal distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) gives you the result. Are you sure the variance is correct though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First notice that:
$$ \begin{align}
x_{t+1} &= \mu+\kappa(x_t-\mu)+\sigma \epsilon_{t+1}\\
& = \mu+\kappa( \mu+\kappa(x_{t-1}-\mu)+\sigma \epsilon_t -\mu)+\sigma \epsilon_{t+1}\\
& = \mu+\kappa( \kappa(x_{t-1}-\mu)+\sigma \epsilon_t)+\sigma \epsilon_{t+1}\\
& = \mu+\kappa( \kappa(x_{t-1}-\mu))+ \kappa \sigma \epsilon_t +\sigma \epsilon_{t+1}
\end{align} $$

Using conditional expectation:
$$ \begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(x_t | x_{t-1}, x_{t+1}) & = \mathbb{E}( \mu+\kappa(x_{t-1}-\mu)+\sigma \epsilon_{t} | x_{t-1}, x_{t+1})\\
& = \mu+\kappa(x_{t-1}-\mu)+\mathbb{E}(\sigma\epsilon_{t} | x_{t-1}, x_{t+1})\\
\end{align} $$

I imagine that the noises $\epsilon_t$ are all independent, right? Then:
$$ \begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(x_t | x_{t-1}, x_{t+1}) & = \mu+\kappa(x_{t-1}-\mu)+\mathbb{E}(\sigma\epsilon_{t} | \kappa \sigma \epsilon_t +\sigma \epsilon_{t+1} = x_{t+1} - (\mu+\kappa( \kappa(x_{t-1}-\mu)))  )\\
\end{align} $$

Now all you need to do is to understand $\mathbb{E}( X | \kappa X+Y )$ where $X,Y \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ with $X,Y$ independent. But the sum of independent gaussians is a gaussian and you know that:
$$ f_{X|X+Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} $$

Can you continue from here?